# How to connect Arduino with Unity3D (using an Android device)?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, arduino

I have found this interesting Project in the Internet and my first question is how to access the data (which is connected via Bluetooth to Android) from within Unity3D.

https://pauldyan.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/my-vr-bike/

I have seen that there is an "asset" for Bluetooth but is there a direct way or a way without the Need of buying that asset?

Regards

Kev

Answer (score 0):

You could, but it would involve writing your own library for both Android and iOS.

I really don't recommend going this route. You would have to write hooks for every single native iOS and Android Bluetooth function. Both operating systems would need hundreds of lines of code and several days of testing to get going.

I'd recommend just buying it. The asset is 10 dollars, which is worth the time saved.